# Why is $\int 2 \cos x \sin x$ $\neq$ $\int \sin 2x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

So I had this school assignment with this question

> $\int (\cos x - \sin x)^2 \ dx$

And through computations I came up with this:

> $\int (\cos x + \sin x )\ dx - \int 2 \cos x \sin x$

And this is where I got stuck, that when I integrate $2 \cos x \sin x$ right away, I would actually get $\color{blue}{x - \sin^2 x + C}$, which is different if I applied the double angle trigonometric identities in $2 \cos x \sin x$ , rewrite it to $\sin 2x$ , and it will give me a different answer, $\color{red}{x + \cos(2x)/2 + C}$

I went to [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/), and it really shows the difference, whether I integrate it right away or apply the trigonometric identity first before integrating

> [image]

> [image]

I tried to plot the points in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), two answers seems close enough that it's just one constant away (particularly $0.5$), but still mathematically not equal.

> [image]

So, does this mean that this trigonometric identity changed the actual answer that I should avoid using it as much as possible. Or this is just an exception? Which one is right? Is it both of the two answers?

I already passed my answer to the teacher, but what I actually did before passing it is integrating right away. But this problem haunts me in sleep that I actually opened my pc to ask this question here. Still learning integration techniques that I got introduced to this kind of problem, that overall it's pretty fun and stressing.

Comment: $(cc-s)^2=c^2+s^2-2cs$.

Comment: @WorshipLyrics Two primitives of the same function can differ by a constant...

Comment: For several reasons this question is not up to our community standards, and I doubt anyone is willing to invest the time and effort to rectify the issues with an edit. Please use MathJax, please embed your photos rather than linking them, and please avoid rambling.

Comment: Your calculation is incorrect: how can you get the term $x$ in "x - sin²x + C"?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on when and what you do the u-substitution, there are at least three ways to calculate $\int 2\sin(x)\cos(x)dx$:

$$
\int 2\sin x\cos x\ dx=\int \sin(2x)\ dx=-\frac12 \cos(2x)+C\tag{1}
$$

$$
\int 2\sin x\cos x\ dx = (\sin x)^2+C\tag{2}
$$

$$
\int 2\sin x\cos x\ dx = -(\cos x)^2+C\tag{3}
$$

These answers are all correct.

In general, if you get (correctly via different methods)
$$
\int f(x)\ dx=F(x)+C,\quad 
\int f(x)\ dx=G(x)+C
$$

then there is some constant $K$ such that $G(x)=F(x)+K$.

---

Recall that $\int f(x)\,dx=F(x)+C$ really means $F'(x)=f(x)$ (on some interval $I$). The solution $F$ is not unique.

To see another example, both the following are correct:
$$
\int \cos(x)\,dx=\sin x+C,\quad \int \cos(x)\,dx=\sin x+1+C
$$

Comment: Thank you for explaining that nature of the constant in general well. I should note that in future lessons

Comment: @WorshipLyrics: you are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The "part of the antiderivative without the $+C$" is not unique, it can always be adjusted by a constant. Confusingly, there are expressions that don't appear to involve constants that nevertheless differ by constants, such as $\cos(x)^2$ and $-\sin(x)^2$. This is what is happening here:

$$\int 2 \sin(x) \cos(x) dx = \sin(x)^2 + C \\
\int \sin(2x) dx = -\frac{1}{2} \cos(2x) + C = -\frac{1}{2} \cos(x)^2 + \frac{1}{2} \sin(x)^2 + C = -\frac{1}{2} + \sin(x)^2 + C$$

where in that last step I used $\cos(x)^2=1-\sin(x)^2$.

These have to be the same thing, because the functions being integrated are the same...and they are the same thing, because $-1/2 + C$ in the second version is just another arbitrary constant. I find this is intuitive after you've "isolated" the constant like I did above, whereas the idea that $\sin(x)^2+C$ and $-\frac{1}{2} \cos(2x) + C$ are the same thing is a bit puzzling on its face.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$x-\sin^2(x)+\color{blue}C=x+\frac{\cos(2x)}2+\color{blue}{C- \frac12}$$

Comment: But the left part didn't equate to the case when I applied the trig identity first before integrating. It doesn't have 1/2 on it, or is that the same?

Answer (score 1):

A common mistake.

$$\int(2\sin x\cos x-\sin 2x)\,dx=C,$$ so

$$\int2\sin x\cos x\,dx=\int\sin 2x\,dx+C$$ for some $C$.

Answer (score -1):

I=∫2cosx sinx dx=2∫cosx sinx dx   .....1)
integration by parts
I=2{cosx∫sinx dx-∫ [d/dx(cosx)]* [ ∫sinx dx ] }dx
I=2{cosx (-cosx)- ∫ [-sinx][-cosx)]dx }
I=-2cos²x - 2∫[sinx][cosx]dx
from.....1)
I=-2cos²x -I
2I=-2cos²x
I=-cos²x  + constant
I=-(1+cos2x)/2 + constant
I=-1/2-cos2x/2 + constant
I=-cos2x/2 + constant-1/2........(-1/2 is also constant)
I=-cos2x/2 +C
∫sin2x dx= -cos2x/2 +C

Comment: Please use MathJax to format the math.